# Tkinter (Python) output random numbers to GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

Noob Alert!!!

Hello, I just started my journey with through python a couple of days ago, so my question will most likely be extremely simple to answer. Basically I have a random number gen. from 1 to 10, this is activated when the "test button is pressed on the windows that pops up. As you can see from the image below the random number appears in the output console on the bottom of the screen, in this case it was a 9. So here's the question, How can I make the random number on the GUI? so when the button is pressed a random number appears on the same window as the button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWd3i.png

Any help is appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("test it is")
root.grid()

def randnum(event):
    import random
    value =random.randint(1,10)
    print(value)


button_1 = Button(root, text="test")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>",randnum)
button_1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Give us a minimal working example and read "How to ask" before.

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Please do not link to a picture of code. That is essentially useless to us. Please take the time to properly embed and format your code in the question.

Comment: thanks for the feedback on my question, next time I post here I will make sure to put everything you guys have said into consideration. Fortunetly Rajat Surana was abke to answer my q.

Comment: @CheapoPC ... do accept the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("test it is")
root.grid()

def randnum(event):
 import random
 value =random.randint(1,10)
 print(value)
 updateDisplay(value)

def updateDisplay(myString):
 displayVariable.set(myString)


button_1 = Button(root, text="test")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>",randnum)
button_1.pack()
displayVariable = StringVar()
displayLabel = Label(root, textvariable=displayVariable)
displayLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[Here is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUWsE.png)You have to create a Label with a Button, whose value will get updated when you click on button.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
win = tk.Tk()


def test_button_click():
    label_val.set(randint(1, 10))

my_button = tk.Button(win, text='Test Button',
                      command=test_button_click)
my_button.grid(column=0, row=0)
label_val = tk.IntVar()
my_Label = tk.Label(win, textvariable=label_val)
my_Label.grid(column=1, row=0)
win.mainloop()
```

This will achieve what you are requesting -- create a tk window, add a button and label, use the callback `test_button_click` to set the labels int var when the button is clicked.